# sql server The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    SELECT TOP 28 *
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [DATECOL]
            ,[CODE ARTICLE]
            ,[CODE SITE]
            ,[CODE STRUCTURE]
        FROM [VENTE] T2
        WHERE PROMO = 0
            AND ([CODE ARTICLE] IS NOT NULL)
            AND ([CODE STRUCTURE] IS NOT NULL)
            AND ([PRIX DE REVIENT] IS NOT NULL)
            AND [CODE ARTICLE] = '    714180291'
            AND [CODE SITE] = '    7'
        ORDER BY [DATECOL]
        ) T
```

I got the following error

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 The ORDER BY clause is invalid in
>   views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table
>   expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

How to correct it ?

Comment: remove `order by` in the inner query.

Comment: Move the ORDER BY to the main query. (Why a derived table???)

Comment: @vkp I am looking to get the first max datecol

Comment: Put the order by in the outer query

Comment: @sagi it returns incorrect records

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your query.

Comment: Just a side note: Isn't it awful always to have to use those brackets? Name your columns without blanks (e.g. `CODE_ARTICLE`) and you don't need them any more. Moreover: Why do you store numeric values in strings with leading blanks? This is error-prone and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the below code

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 28 [DATECOL]
        ,[CODE ARTICLE]
        ,[CODE SITE]
        ,[CODE STRUCTURE]
    FROM [VENTE] T2
    WHERE PROMO = 0
        AND ([CODE ARTICLE] IS NOT NULL)
        AND ([CODE STRUCTURE] IS NOT NULL)
        AND ([PRIX DE REVIENT] IS NOT NULL)
        AND [CODE ARTICLE] = '    714180291'
        AND [CODE SITE] = '    7'
    ORDER BY [DATECOL]
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Why downvoting without an explanation? (I'll upvote, just to compensate.)

Comment: Thanks. I have used these type queries in daily work @jarlh

Comment: @sagi nobody suggested it in comments as here i didn't took any outer query

Comment: Its similar.. didn't say it because of that, just guessed:P

Answer (score 1):

order by clause should place in outer query. Use below query

```
select top 28 * 
from 
(select  distinct [datecol],[Code Article],[Code Site] ,[Code Structure]

           from [Vente] t2
            where promo = 0
            and ([Code Article] is not null) and ([Code Structure] is not null) and ([Prix de Revient] is not null)and     [Code Article]= '    714180291' and [Code Site]='    7' 

) t 
order by [datecol]
```